# Batch processing of events from ms azure eventhub in golang

Tags: go, batch-processing, azure-eventhub, azure-sdk

I read some docs about how to process events in golang from AZURE eventhub but that's all one by one and I couldn't find batch processing of events anywhere. That seems kinda useless for ETL operations. Does anyone know how to batch process events with the golang library?

Because currently I looked at the https://github.com/Azure/azure-event-hubs-go/blob/master/_examples/helloworld/consumer/main.go but the handler is a function that accepts a single event as parameter. More effective would be if there was some handler that can accept batch of events. Because if I would want to do some database transactions based on the events I would have to make one transaction per event. I also cannot just send it to some other goroutine because If i make a transaction in database based on processed events I have to make sure that a checkpoint is set after the batch. Just like when working with AWS kinesis in AWS lambda.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Golang concurrency, processing batches of items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51520830/golang-concurrency-processing-batches-of-items)

Comment: This question is about azure eventhubs batch processing, not some random batchprocessing

Comment: Link I gave you should help to batch data. I am not sure what API Azure has to run these batches. It was not clear from your question what part of the process is not clear for you. Your question may not get enough attention because it is too broad.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the question is invalid. Since I am free to store checkpoints whenerver I want (not only after batch process, but after multiple batches processed). I am free to use this one-by-one api and forward the events to some custom batch processor. All the events contain an offset so I can store a checkpoint whenever I want in the custom batch processor.

PS: The linked azure examples mention batch processing, but it's actually batch writing not batch reading.