# Iterating over 10,000 postgresql rows take very long (20 minutes) with golang, how do i speed things up?

Tags: postgresql, go, concurrency, channel, goroutine

> Please see **UPDATES** below

I have a function that queries a postrgesql database using [gorm][1] and then iterates over all the rows returned and performs some simple calculations like checking for time different since last notifications and price changes etc

Disappointingly it takes like **1.2 seconds per 10 rows** and this scales linearly, thank goodness

**so 10,000 rows takes approximately 20 minutes**
i tested it and the scaling is very linear, **5,000 rows will take roughly 10 minutes** etc

How do i reduce this so i can complete the task i want to perform in like seconds? I am planning having to iterate over **1,000,000 rows** as my expectations and **i want to be able to complete this task in 60 seconds or less over 1 million rows**

**BACK STORY:**

> i initially built this app using python fastapi framework and i got somewhat similar
> performance, python like 2x slower...but i was told golang is very
> fast and stupid fast compared to dynamically typed python, but about
> 2x performance, is that really the case?
>
> So now that i rebuilt the whole app in golang and i still get this
> crappy numbers, it is time to reach out to my beloved stackoverflow
> community for help
>
> I am all ears to all advice to what is best way to approach this task
> i am trying to perform. Like i said i can have 1 million rows to
> process, so i am looking for a future proof solution and something
> that is like best way to do something like this
>
> I have the functions of what the tasks is doing below so you guys can
> see exactly what is involved in the iterations.

```
package main

import (
    ...
    ...
    ...
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func SendNotification() error {

    var productPrices []models.ProductPrice
    database.DB.Where("status = ?", "enabled").Find(&productPrices)

    timeNow := time.Now()
    for _, productPrice := range productPrices {
    
        if productPrice.LastNotified.IsZero() != true {
            lastNotified := productPrice.LastNotified
            timeNotified, _ := time.Parse(time.RFC3339, lastNotified.String())
            timeDuration := timeNow.Sub(timeNotified)
            timeDurationSeconds := timeDuration.Seconds()
            
            if uint64(timeDurationSeconds) < productPrice.Cooldown {
                continue
            }
        }

        // call an external API endpoint to get the current price of product based on product name
        setPrice := providers.GetProductPrice(providers.ProviderOne, productPrice.Name)

        if float64(setPrice) == 0 {
            continue
        }

        if productPrice.Type == "above" && productPrice.Price >= float64(setPrice) {
            continue
        }
        
        if productPrice.Type == "below" && productPrice.Price <= float64(setPrice) {
            continue
        }
        
        var user models.User

        database.DB.Where("id = ?", productPrice.UserId).First(&user)

        userTo := user.Email
        notificationMessage := fmt.Sprintf(`<!DOCTYPE html>
        <html lang="en">
        <body>
            <p> Welcome back %s
        </body>
        </html>`, user.Email)

        emailSubject := fmt.Sprintf("%s product notification for %s", productPrice.Name, user.Email)


        if productPrice.NotificationMethod == "email" {
            NotificationMethodEmail(SendEmail, userTo, notificationMessage, emailSubject)
        }
        if productPrice.NotificationMethod == "sms" {
            NotificationMethodSMS(SendSMS, userTo, notificationMessage)
        }
    }

    fmt.Println("processed this number of rows: ", len(productPrices), "\n")
    return nil  
}

func SendNotificationCron() {
    for {
        // i deally i will be running this every 2 minutes
        // when am able to speed things up to less than 60 seconds
        time.Sleep(30 * time.Minute)
        startTime := time.Now()
        SendNotification()
        endTime := time.Now()
        cronDuration := endTime.Sub(startTime)
        fmt.Println("duration: ", cronDuration, "\n")
    }
}


func main() {
    go notifications.SendNotificationCron()
}
```

and here are test results

```
golang-task       | processed this number of rows:  10 
golang-task       | 
golang-task       | duration:  1.377023066s 
golang-task       | 
golang-task       | processed this number of rows:  10 
golang-task       | 
golang-task       | duration:  1.097972596s

golang-task       | prcoessed this number of rows:  4000 
golang-task       | 
golang-task       | duration:  7m59.548090252s 
golang-task       | 
golang-task       | prcoessed this number of rows:  4000 
golang-task       | 
golang-task       | duration:  7m41.425781293s

golang-task       | processed this number of rows:  8000 
golang-task       | 
golang-task       | duration:  14m10.168135161s
golang-task       | 
golang-task       | processed this number of rows:  8000 
golang-task       | 
golang-task       | duration:  16m2.544522843s
```

Your help is very highly appreciated
Thanks in advance

> **UPDATES:**

[1]

**Issue is with the line where the external API call is made per row**

I updated DB query to use JOIN as suggested from comments, but still taking similar time to complete

So i decided to remove the external API piece and hard coded a float value to use for all row iterations instead and here is what i get after removing the external API call part

```
golang-task       | prcoessed this number of rows:  1000 
golang-task       | 
golang-task       | duration:  20.645238ms 
golang-task       | 
golang-task       | prcoessed this number of rows:  1000 
golang-task       | 
golang-task       | duration:  23.839578ms

golang-task       | prcoessed this number of rows:  10000 
golang-task       | 
golang-task       | duration:  252.026702ms 
golang-task       | 
golang-task       | prcoessed this number of rows:  10000 
golang-task       | 
golang-task       | duration:  234.026715ms
```

So seems issue is the external API call part.
What can i do in this case now?
[1]: https://gorm.io

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/241507/discussion-on-question-by-uberrebu-iterating-over-10-000-postgresql-rows-take-ve).

Answer (score 0):

You are doing query for every user. So your program slows down linearly because of this. There is a basic solution for this problem. I don't know your data structures so take this answer as guide to solve problem.

You must do JOIN in here:

`database.DB.Where("status = ?", "enabled").Find(&productPrices)`

And you must remove this query:

`database.DB.Where("id = ?", productPrice.UserId).First(&user)`

and take data from `productPrices.User` instead of querying n times for user.

Comment: updated to use JOIN but taking similar time to complete, so issue was not the DB calls as those are very fast...issue is the external API calls..that is what is causing things to be very slow